# Fancybox callback in quicksand plugin

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am having trouble with writing a callback for `Fancybox`. I had used a callback for `Slimbox` in my quicksand.js file which worked fine, but recently changed to `Fancybox`, since it is mobile friendly and `slimbox` is not. Ok so basically the page in question works fine, ie all calls to `Fancybox` work, until you execute Quicksand, then `Fancybox` is dead in the water. I know I need to integrate the callback in my quicksand.js plugin but having trouble doing that. To add to the complication, each image on the page calls a different `Fancybox` script in the  section of the page, as when you hover over the image, it brings up a mask with two links to two different `Fancybox` galleries.

Here is the code in the head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancyboxLauncher1").on("click", function () {
$(".fancybox-buttons1").eq(0).trigger("click");
return false;
});

$('.fancybox-buttons1').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
closeBtn  : false,
helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},
});

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancyboxLauncher2").on("click", function () {
$(".fancybox-buttons2").eq(0).trigger("click");
return false;
});

$('.fancybox-buttons2').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
closeBtn  : false,
helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},
});

});
</script>
```

Now here is the HTML code where one of the images calls `fancybox`

```
<div class="portfolio-hover">

<div class="mask"></div>
<ul>

<li class="portfolio-zoom">
<a class="fancyboxLauncher1" href="img/project/gallery/anodising/thumbnail.jpg"
title="Click Here To View The Gallery">zoom</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<a class="fancybox-buttons1" href="img/project/gallery/alert.png" title="Image Gallery
Will Be Available From April 2014">zoom</a>
</div>
</li>                                   

<li class="portfolio-single">
<a class="fancyboxLauncher2" href="img/project/gallery/anodising/thumbnail.jpg"
title="Click Here For Stage Information">single</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<a class="fancybox-buttons2" href="img/project/gallery/alert.png" title="Information
Page Will Be Available From April 2014">single</a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

As I said the page works fine, enabling you to have two separate `fancybox` triggers depending on which link you click on (zoom or single) that the mask brings up when you hover over an image. I had to differentiate by calling fancyboxLauncher1 and fancyboxLauncher2 to get this to work.

Anyway the problem is NOT this code it is once you run quicksand.js to re-order the images, then `Fancybox` does not work as mentioned, unless you refresh the page, which of course sets the images back into their default pre-quicksand positions!

As I said I had this all working fine with `Slimbox`, so here is the callback `javascript` code that is now at the base of the quicksand.js file that calls `fancybox` once it has run

```
// call quicksand and assign transition parameters
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
duration: 800,
easing: 'swing'
},function() {
// reload other plugins
runfancybox();
});
return false;
```

The only important line here is the "runfancybox();" one, as I have not modified any adjoining lines, since changing from `Slimbox`. This line presumably then refers to the very top of this same .js file where I have inserted the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/* ================ FANCYBOX ================ */

if(jQuery().fancybox) {

$(".fancyboxLauncher1").on("click", function () {
$(".fancybox-buttons1").eq(0).trigger("click");
return false;
});

$('.fancybox-buttons1').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
closeBtn  : false,
helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},
});

$(".fancyboxLauncher2").on("click", function () {
$(".fancybox-buttons2").eq(0).trigger("click");
return false;
});

$('.fancybox-buttons2').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
closeBtn  : false,
helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},
});

}

unmodified js script continues from this point onwards

/* ================ PORTFOLIO QUICKSAND FILTER ================ */
```

Basically I don't know whether I need a callback for each possible trigger ie fancboxLauncher1 AND fancboxLauncher2 or do I just need a way to re-initiate `fancybox` with some sort of simple function call?

I know this has to tie in with the call at the end of the quicksand plugin. I also know that this is where my problems lies, ie correctly inserting a callback function into the quicksand plugin. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: OK I have solved this by adding the same script as a callback in the quicksand.js file. Only trouble is, as I found, becuase the JS is called once on the page and again when you run the quicksand.js file, when you click on the button helper it is causing the whole button console to shift right. This does not happen if you dont run the quicksand filter, ie initial fancybox script has only thus far run once on the page, once you sort the images, after quicksand filter runs, if you then click on an image then click on the button helper, you will see what I mean

Comment: Problem solved but it has created another...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401398/fancybox-button-console-moving-sideways-on-clicking-next-previous-and-duplicatin